# Swagger json file in API Manager

Tags: azure, azure-functions, swagger, openapi, wso2-api-manager

I have deployed my Azure Function behind an API Manager.
Is it possible for the API Manager to expose the same swagger endpoint as the azure function.

For e.g :
If the function app swagger url is :
https://myazurefunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/swagger.json

I need
https://myapimanagerbaseurl/api/swagger.json

I tried accessing the url but it says not found

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if API-M can be a passthrough so that when someone calls API-M they are redirected to the Azure Function. Well not exactly that. All of the security, quality of service, and other features of API-M would still need to be in play if someone is calling the API from API-M.

You have a couple options for exposing the swagger data, but the most significant one is using the "[Import Open API](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/create-api/create-rest-api/create-a-rest-api-from-an-openapi-definition/)" feature. This brings your swagger definition into API-M.

The second option would be to add the original swagger.json link into your documentation. But that's not as beneficial as the first option.